# synchronized methods can execute simultaneously?

Tags: java

I have created 2 objects and 2 threads.
Assume m1() and m2() are synchronized methods.

t1.m1();
t2.m2();
 can both threads can execute simultaneously ? is it possible both synchronized methods can execute simultaneously?

Comment: By the way, you should change your code to `o1.m1()` and `o2.m2()` to make it clearer. `t` sounds like `thread`. You can even understand it using a single synchronized method `m1()`. And I think that would be better for understanding the point.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization happens on specific instances. Synchronized methods synchronize on the instances the method is called on. Thus, `t1.m1()` and `t2.m2()` *can* execute simultaneously if and only if `t1` and `t2` refer to different instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if both are non-static and are executed using two different instances.

**Explanation added.**

Because `monitor` is actually associated with the instance. So, if one thread acquired the lock on one instance, the thread is free to invoke the method on the other instance.

Answer (score 1):

They can execute simultaneously, since synchronized methods lock on the instance.

```
synchronized void someMethod(){
}
```

is the same as

```
void someMethod(){
   synchronized(this){
   }
}
```

So every instance has its own lock to synchronise on.

Static methods use the class instance instead (SomeClass.class).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if they are instance methods of different instances, they are synchronization does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is always done on a monitor. Only one thread can access a monitor at a time.

When you are synchronizating methods, the monitor is either the object (non-static) or the Class-object (static methods).

You should think of

```
public synchronized void myMethod(){
  ...
}
```

as:

```
public void myMethod(){
  synchronized (this) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Since you are having two independent object instances with a synchronized method, you have 2 different monitors.
Result: Both Threads can work simultaneously.